# Error in Jasper Report Generation

Tags: java, unix, jasper-reports

I have designed a JRXML on Jaspersoft Studio 5.1.0, able to generate a CSV format report on Eclipse and Windows machine. When i export the java code onto Unix server, getting below error.

Java Version of Unix Server : "1.7.0.08"

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:148)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:464)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:861)
        at com.infy.ui.mig.compare.MigrationUXAndONSCompare.GenerateReport(MigrationUXAndONSCompare.java:518)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.setTtf(SimpleFontFace.java:182)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFace(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:364)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:290)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:254)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:215)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:184)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:999)
        at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:876)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.setTtf(SimpleFontFace.java:174)
        ... 19 more
```

Java Code :

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint;
            JasperReport jasperReport;
            HashMap jasperParams = new HashMap();

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(jrxmlFile);
            JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
            jasperReport.isIgnorePagination();
            Document document = JRXmlUtils.parse(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(writeFileDir));

            jasperParams.put(jasperReport.isIgnorePagination(), Boolean.TRUE);
            jasperParams.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, jasperParams);

            JRCsvExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, csvReportName);
            exporter.exportReport();
```

JRXML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="HCOTA_RTACOF" language="groovy" pageWidth="3500" pageHeight="4000" columnWidth="3460" columnSpacing="37" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="b857e321-5d0f-4309-a5f5-950316db1f9d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="XmlDataSource_HRDM_ARD"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="62525010-7a4a-47a7-b029-c7502b171ae9">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="field_name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="group-name-ons" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field-type[@type = "ons"]/group-name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="page-name-ons" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field-type[@type = "ons"]/page-name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="XPath">
        <![CDATA[/menu-compare/field-details/fields]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="field_exists" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@existence]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="82" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="120" splitType="Immediate">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="78cd7b95-378a-47a7-a2e6-635677759067" x="10" y="60" width="70" height="30" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Map Type"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="a11ecb4a-06f1-400f-953f-e39edbcf3d9f" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="80" y="60" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Back End Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="40a166e8-1aa0-45e8-a10c-ecf61f6b2f5a" x="150" y="60" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Group Name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c19e0438-7cf9-499e-80d4-7e2f8caaa54b" x="220" y="60" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page Name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="f80aa2dd-1bdd-41fe-82f2-59b4e56d4b28" x="10" y="40" width="1760" height="60"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="c1fe8920-0512-41bc-9f79-8fcbc61ac067">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("/fields/field")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="125" width="1760">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="8d3ab036-d155-4f07-9345-dd37dd3f7101" x="70" y="15" width="70" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="575757aa-2b24-446e-aa79-ea0c5eb02049" x="140" y="15" width="70" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{group-name-ons}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="09512867-0754-4544-991f-8dd4ffc7d8c6" x="210" y="15" width="70" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{page-name-ons}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="fd3813e4-e26d-48ec-8519-c2c25780f48c" x="10" y="55" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_exists}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Could be some missing X-libs. I'm struggling with the same problem: Two linux boxes, on one no problems, on the other your exception. Do you have X11 installed on your linux box?

Answer (score 1):

I think `pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"` is causing the problem. There are two things to consider here.

1. When you are exporting your report and want Helvetica-Bold to appear in it, then you'll to create font-extension for it, unless your JVM already as Helvetica-Bold with it.
2. You would have to create custom styles in the jrxml file and use fonts there and apply style to elements in case of using font extension.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just seeing your exception stack trace... it says

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
```

Probably in your JRXML template you might be using some font which is not available in your application

Comment: Where are you trying to deploy the JRXML file? Are you using some app server?

Comment: Are you using some custom fonts in your JRXML template?

Comment: I want to generate a CSV report from an XML file. Generating it with the help of JRXML file. I'm not using any app server.

Comment: Not using any, have shared the JRXML template in the question section.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure out a similar problem since yesterday, and finally found an answer that fixed the problem for me **(please see the link below)**. This was only happening in our QA environment, but not on my local desktop machine.

Shortly, the error message is pretty misleading and the actual problem is `java.awt.Front not being able to write the Java-temp-directory (java.io.tmpdir)` as described in the original answer below. All I had to do is create a Tomcat temp directory manually (which was never created before in QA environment). After that, it just started working fine.

[Original answer that I found](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/543492/javaioioexception-problem-reading-font-data#node-800556)